# 'Create service' for a Cluster with Ec2 type is giving error in AWS console

Tags: amazon-ecs

Trying out sample ECS with EC2 type in AWS free tier.
Created a Cluster for ec2 instance.
Then created task-def for ec2 resources with image uri - public.ecr.aws/ubuntu/nginx:latest,  OS : Linux/X86_64, image t2.micro.
While creating/deploying the service, getting error on selecting the task-def created.

*There was an error deploying nginx-service
Resource handler returned message: "Error occurred during operation 'ECS Deployment Circuit Breaker was triggered'." (RequestToken: 1ab71394-b41e-190a-df10-6a87d62a7915, HandlerErrorCode: GeneralServiceException)*

task-def-json

```
{
    "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:ap-northeast-1:930446195568:task-definition/ecs-task-def:1",
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "nginx",
            "image": "public.ecr.aws/ubuntu/nginx:latest",
            "cpu": 0,
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "name": "nginx-80-tcp",
                    "containerPort": 80,
                    "hostPort": 80,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                    "appProtocol": "http"
                }
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "environment": [],
            "environmentFiles": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": []
        }
    ],
    "family": "ecs-task-def",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::930446195568:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "networkMode": "bridge",
    "revision": 1,
    "volumes": [],
    "status": "ACTIVE",
    "placementConstraints": [],
    "compatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2"
    ],
    "cpu": "512",
    "memory": "1024",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "cpuArchitecture": "X86_64",
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "registeredAt": "2023-02-15T17:11:45.596Z",
    "registeredBy": "arn:aws:iam::930446195568:user/admin_user",
    "tags": []
}
```

Comment: To give us all the details of your task definition, can you go to the JSON representation of your task definition, copy that, click "Edit" on your question, and paste that in?

Comment: @Mark B Hope this helps. Also I am trying this from the new AWS console. And did not find any video on that...so may have missed something.

Comment: You appear to have edited your question to change the error message to a completely different error message. Did you fix the previous issue and now you are encountering a new issue? The previous error was a deployment error, but this new error appears to be a run-time error. You need to check your ECS container's logs now to see why the containers are failing.

Comment: Was trying out different things. Best is if you can give pointer to some video which gives the steps to create ECS cluster of type Ec2 in the new AWS UI.
By container logs you mean Cloudwatch logs? As a beginner in AWS, not very conversant with all that. Is there a way to have a video session with you to get to know this?
Hope this is not a bother to you and is taken in the right community spirit of a fellow technologist.

Comment: Yes CloudWatch logs. It is unreasonable to expect people giving free advice on the Internet to get on a video session to help you. And it is considered off-topic on this site to request off-site tutorials. If you are having that much trouble with the new ECS UI why don't you just switch back to the old UI?

Comment: Thats exactly what Ive done, switched to old UI. But the curiosity and my developer urge stays. Was tempted about the video call, since I saw you as AWS certified. Of course if you have the time or inclination, we can always work out  something for 1-1 mentoring. Since this is not the right place, do not wish to say anything beyond this.